# How can I get Android Support Library v4 version?

Tags: android

I download Android Support Library v4 from net but I don't know its version.How can I get that version? The following is the information of this document：

name：android-support-v4.jar

MD5: A373357C77B3BE76070D82BC0F5A503D

SHA1: B6C138BA72CE38BEDA559DF33D369856854FD6F5

CRC32: 2490116E

down links：http://pan.baidu.com/s/1kUR8wHh

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK can show the version of Android support Repository, and make sure you download Android Support Repository by using Android SDK Manager.

[image: Android SDK]

If you really want to add an old support lib, you can check the version under Android studio. Right click your project, select "Open Module Settings" -> then select your app modules -> "Dependencies" . You can check your support lib version.

[image: Dependencies]

Comment: @einveme Yes, this approach can be found in the current version of the sdk corresponding support-v4 packet,
But I can not know the version of the current project support-v4 packet,
Is there any way to know?